how to get my chat bot to remember custom responses in discord then put it in intents.json python
hello am trying to get my discord bot to remeber what its learned after i shut it down but each time i boot it up again to test it forget everything its learned
heres the code
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json
import asyncio
import random

# Load intents from intents.json
with open('intents.json', 'r') as intents_file:
    intents_data = json.load(intents_file)
    intents = intents_data.get('intents', [])

# Load custom responses from custom_responses.json
try:
    with open('custom_responses.json', 'r') as custom_responses_file:
        custom_responses = json.load(custom_responses_file)
except FileNotFoundError:
    custom_responses = {}  # Initialize an empty dictionary if the file doesn't exist

# Initialize the bot
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name} ({bot.user.id})')


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return  # Ignore messages from other bots

    # Check for custom responses first
    if message.content.lower() in custom_responses:
        await message.channel.send(custom_responses[message.content.lower()])
    else:
        # If no custom response, check predefined intents
        for intent in intents:
            if any(pattern.lower() in message.content.lower() for pattern in intent['patterns']):
                response = random.choice(intent['responses'])
            `your text`    await message.channel.send(response)
                break
        else:
            await message.channel.send("I'm not sure how to respond. Could you provide a custom response?")

    await bot.process_commands(message)


@bot.command()
async def learn(ctx, *, response: str):
    """
    Command to add a custom response.
    Usage: !learn <user_input> <custom_response>
    Example: !learn favorite_color Blue
    """
    user_input, custom_response = response.split(maxsplit=1)
    custom_responses[user_input.lower()] = custom_response
    await ctx.send(f"Learned: '{user_input}' -> '{custom_response}'")


@bot.event
async def on_disconnect():
    # Save custom responses to custom_responses.json when the bot disconnects
    with open('custom_responses.json', 'w') as custom_responses_file:
        json.dump(custom_responses, custom_responses_file, indent=4)


print("Bot is starting...")
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(bot.start('TOKEN'))

then you got the custom_responses.json
{
"user_input_1": "custom_response_1",
"user_input_2": "custom_response_2"
}
then the intents.json
{
"intents": [
    {
        "tag": "google",
        "patterns": [
            "google",
            "search",
            "internet"
        ],
        "responses": [
            "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&pp=ygUXbmV2ZXIgZ29ubmEgZ2l2ZSB5b3UgdXA%3D"
        ]
    },
    {
        "tag": "greeting",
        "patterns": [
            "Hi there",
            "How are you",
            "Is anyone there?",
            "Hey",
            "Hola",
            "Hello",
            "Good day",
            "Namaste",
            "yo"
        ],
        "responses": [
            "Hello",
            "Good to see you again",
            "Hi there, how can I help?"
        ],
        "context": [
            ""
        ]
    }

etc
any help would be helpful to me thanks you for you time as well
i want it to remember what you tell it like if you say !learn cat cat is good next time you boot it you say cat i want it to say cat is good

i did it just added a shut down command i hope this helped someone out there
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return  # Ignore messages from other bots

    # Check for custom responses first
    if message.content.lower() in custom_responses:
        await message.channel.send(custom_responses[message.content.lower()])
    elif message.content.lower() == "quitquit":
        await message.channel.send("Goodnight! Shutting down...")
        await bot.close()  # Shut down the bot
    else:
        # If no custom response, check predefined intents
        for intent in intents:
            if any(pattern.lower() in message.content.lower() for pattern in intent['patterns']):
                response = random.choice(intent['responses'])
                await message.channel.send(response)
                break
        else:
            await message.channel.send("I'm not sure how to respond. Could you provide a custom response?")

    await bot.process_commands(message)


Am I missing something. This doesn't seem like what you were trying to achieve. This code will still be faulty if the bot crashes. I would make a ´update´ command then use that everytime I want to save something to the json file.
